# How is casting implemented internally in Java?

Tags: java, oop

Explanation might require details about internal representation of Java objects and Inheritance, please feel free to elaborate or give references.

Edit: Explaining it for any popular VM will help.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: I think down-casting is just as straight forward. The data is already there if the runtime type of the object is the correct subtype. What exactly is it you have problem grasping?

Comment: No, I already know c++ and was beginning with Java and I know a bit about how it is done in c++, just curious to know how it is done in java.

Comment: I'd say it's the same as in C++, except there's an extra bytecode instruction called `checkcast` that throws an `ClassCastException` if the object is not of the right subtype.

Comment: Edited the question to get the complete overview.

Comment: These types of details can be found in the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5).

Comment: @VinceEmigh Not really. The spec says what needs to be done, not how it needs to be done. In particular, it allows for (but does not specify) optimizations and space/time tradeoffs.

Comment: @yshavit And those things are not properly part of Java; they're implementation details that are notably different, e.g., between HotSpot and Dalvik.

Comment: @chrylis That's definitely true, and the OP should probably specify which specific implementation they want (not even just "HotSpot," but the version). But still, it seems pretty clear to me that the OP is asking specifically about those implementation details.

Comment: @user2614516: You said you already know how it works in C++. Please explain to me how it works in C++ and I promise you to give you an as detailed answer for Java.